# Icinga2 IDO schema

Tags: icinga

I was going through the steps to setup icinga on a server with the icingaweb UI v 2.0 layout as given in their [documentation](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc). I was successful in getting to the setup page, which requires you to put in a token and then follow the steps. Im stuck at this spot (see screenshot) right now which requires you to setup an IDO database which I already did as shown:
[image]

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| icinga             |
| icinga2idomysql    |
| icinga_ido         |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

However I keep getting the error message `Cannot find the IDO schema. Please verify that the given database contains the schema and that the configured user has access to it.`. Can anyone help me or point out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Same question over here: https://serverfault.com/questions/729345/icinga-ido-schema-error

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have installed "icinga2-ido-mysql". Follow the below steps. Below is for ubuntu servers.

```
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client icinga2-ido-mysql
icinga2 feature enable ido-mysql
icinga2 feature enable command
service icinga2 restart
```

Restart icinga make sure you are using "icinga2" as db for ido scehma which is created once you successfully completes icinga2-ido-mysql

Answer (score 2):

Use the credentials set during setup of icinga2 it self.

If you forgot what credentials were used, the psql IDO config file on Ubuntu is located her:

`/etc/icinga2/features-enabled/ido-pgsql.conf`

It can look like this:

```
/**
 * The db_ido_pgsql library implements IDO functionality
 * for PostgreSQL.
 */

library "db_ido_pgsql"

object IdoPgsqlConnection "ido-pgsql" {
  user = "icinga2",
  password = "<PASSWORD>",
  host = "localhost",
  database = "icinga2"
}
```

If that's not the location, during restart of icinga2 you can see what config files are in play and their location:

`tail -f /var/log/icinga2/startup.log`

While that is running, in another terminal do:

`service icinga2 restart`

Comment: This was my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what helped me on my CentOS 7 installation:

```
cp /usr/share/icinga2-ido-mysql/schema/mysql.sql .
sed -i "1iuse icinga;" mysql.sql
mysql -u root -p < mysql.sql
```

I found it here:

https://lists.icinga.org/pipermail/icinga-users/2014-July/008424.html

Comment: If you accidentally kill the db that was installed by apt, you can restore it with the *.sql file mentioned above. Useful.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to specify in the settings of the base with the name.

Comment: @letsc hi,I meet the same issue, and do not know <the base with the name>.please tell me how you solve it

Comment: get solved. Database Name = `icinga_ido` => Database Name = `icinga2`

Comment: I've got the same problem (and he: http://serverfault.com/questions/729345/icinga-ido-schema-error  also). Could you maybe describe the solution more clear? When I've got a database in mysql, which is called icinga_ido, why should the database name which I give icinga be icinga2? For me, with icinga_ido defined, this does not work.